# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() work incorrect

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I try to run python application on Android in my application.
This script work correct in **Better Terminal Emulator Pro**

```
su
busybox chroot /data/local/debian /bin/bash
/usr/bin/python /usr/src/script.py
```

Then I enter value

```
>>value1
result
```

But if I tried it in my app that:

```
String line;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox chroot /data/local/debpsla /bin/bash");
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

proc.waitFor();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){ 
   publishProgress(line); 
}
```

Command **ls** return not right list of files. This means that root directory don't changed.
What I do incorrect?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are running each command separately as they start a new process each and with only the JVM's context.  This means you are running `su` and `busybox chroot /data/local/debpsla /bin/bash` and `ls` as concurrent and unrelated processes.

If you want one to follow the other you have do this all in one process.  I suspect writing a script which you execute will be easier.

Comment: I think your answer may not be clear that each call to exec starts a new process and is therefore unrelated to the previous call.

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350862/2143772 example. But also chroot didn't work.