# Efficient execution and output stream redirection of process spawned with Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, stream, runtime.exec

I have a script which executes a program several times, producing about 350 lines of output to both STDERR and STDOUT. Now, I need to execute the script in Java, thereby printing the output streams to their original destinations. So, basically, I execute the script from inside a Java class, maintaining the original behavior for the user.

The way I do this is inspired from suggestions like [Reading streams from java Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343066/reading-streams-from-java-runtime-exec) and, functionally, works fine.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
new Thread(new ProcessInputStreamHandler(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
new Thread(new ProcessInputStreamHandler(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
return p.waitFor();
```

And the class `ProcessInputStreamHandler`:

```
class ProcessInputStreamHandler implements Runnable {
    private BufferedReader in_reader;
    private PrintStream out_stream;

    public ProcessInputStreamHandler(final InputStream in_stream, final PrintStream out_stream) {
        this.in_reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_stream));
        this.out_stream = out_stream;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = in_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out_stream.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {throw new Error(e);}

        out_stream.flush();
    }
}
```

Now regarding my problem statement: While the execution of the script takes about 17 seconds, the "encapsulated" execution takes at least 21 seconds. Where do I lose these 4 or more seconds?

I already tried using a `ProcessBuilder` with redirection of STDERR to STDOUT, using POSIX vfork with libraries like https://github.com/axiak/java_posix_spawn, using a byte buffer instead of a `BufferedReader`... everything with no positive result at all.

Are there any suggestings? I understand that there will be some performance loss, but 4 seconds seem to be a bit much to me...

Appreciate any suggestions!

Best Regards and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I daresay 4 seconds would be the JVM warmup time: e.g. loading jvm executable into memory, loading standard library, loading classes, etc.

Comment: I would guess it is the the additional scheduling that you introduced using your threads which might be slowing you down. Did you try having your script write to a file instead of `STDERR` and `STDOUT`? Then you could run the Java script wrapper without the `ProcessInputStreamHandler` objects to check whether that still takes an additional 4 seconds. If this is the case non-blocking I/O (nio) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way for your task is to use Java 7 and

```
return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

If that doesn’t help, I think there’s nothing you can do as every other approach would add even more code to your runtime environment that has to be processed.

Comment: Nice one-liner, certainly good to clean up the code. Unfortunately, my test revealed that it  does not provide any performance benefits...

Comment: The important point is the `inheritIO()` as it does not require you to execute any Java code for the output redirection but let the operating system handle this. If this feature does not improve the performance, the reason for the performance problem does not lie in this code at all.

Comment: The delay probably stems from loading the "outer" program into the JVM. I made further measurements which support this view. Thanks for all suggestions and the Java 7 hint which was new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will improve performance or not, but you can try the [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) library which while also providing non-blocking (asynchronous) I/O will also use vfork on Linux, which does decrease process launch times (and memory overhead) quite a bit.