# Java 8 on Windows 7: runtime.exec does not terminate

Tags: java, windows-7, java-8, runtime.exec

I want to run a jar script from within a Java program. The command is tested to run without problems if pasted sloley to the Windows cmd. 
However, my Java script stucks at `p.waitFor()`.

```
public class MyClass{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
       // create a new process
       System.out.println("Creating Process...");
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("U:\\locallib\\jdk-8u65-windows-x64\\tools\\bin\\java.exe -Xmx4g -jar U:\\path\\to\\my.jar arg1 arg2");
       System.out.println("Process is running...");

       p.waitFor();
       System.out.println("Process is terminated...");
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Ouput:

```
Creating Process...
Process is running...
```

...and nothing else.

Comment: Can you see it still running in the task manager? Does it wait for input or anything like that?

Comment: It's listed, but seems to sleep. ...and it doesn't require input if running sloley in the Windows cmd.

Comment: i think you dont have a problem with the code

Comment: The jar script writes to STDOUT. Might that cause the problem?

Comment: You generally need to read the Process getInputStream (and also the getErrorStream), if you don't the program may become blocked when the buffers become full.

Comment: If you don’t want to read the output of the sub-process, you can redirect it to you own stdout using a `ProcessBuilder` and `inheritIO`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19658154/2711488).

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.