# Java Command is not executed

Tags: java, linux

I have a Java-App, which should execute an sh command.
My command looks like `sudo /bin/sh -c "echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export"` and when I execute this in the command prompt of my computer it works, but not with my Java-Programm.


The Programm-line looks like this:

```
System.out.println(CmdExecutor.execute("sudo /bin/sh -c \"echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export\""));
```

```
public class CmdExecutor {

public static String execute(String[] cmd) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    }

    return output.toString();
}

public static String execute(String cmd) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

}

Can someone help me?

Comment: try ....exec(cmd.toString());

Comment: Pretty sure you need to provide a password when you sudo.

Comment: Add a reader to the ouputstrem and see if you get an error. Example you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343066/reading-streams-from-java-runtime-exec)

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you expect to supply a password to sudo, or is it supposed to work without a password? Does sudo or the shell emit any error messages? Do you get an exception? What is the exception and the stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708087/how-to-execute-bash-command-with-sudo-privileges-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute system commands (linux/bsd) using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java)

Comment: I get this error `7: 1: 7: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

- Multiple arguments need to be split in Java already.
- Authentication with `sudo`.

### Multiple arguments need to be split.

If you run `exec("a b")`, the system will look for a command named `a b` as one single String command name.

If you run `exec("a", "b"), the system will look for a command named`a`and pass`b` as argument to that program.

So what you want to do is `execute("sudo", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export")`.

### `sudo` might require authentication

When you execute commands with `sudo`, an authentication will be performed. If you execute multiple `sudo` commands from the same process, the system will cache the authentication for convenience, but basically the authentication is required.

The authentication with `sudo` usually means that you need to supply a password.

The reason why you `sudo` this is that `/sys/class/gpio/export` has permissions `-w-------` (200) owned by `root root`, which means nobody can read it and only root can write it.

You have a few options:

- Change the permissions of that file so that everybody can write it (not recommended): `chmod a+w /sys/class/gpio/export`.
- Change the permissions of that file so that the user in question can write it: `setfacl -m user:cher:w /sys/class/gpio/export` - note that this only works if your `sysfs` is mounted with `acl` option, and usually it isn't. I don't know if it's even possible to mount `sysfs` with `acl` option, I haven't tried myself.
- Pipe the password to the sudo command: `exec("echo password | sudo /bin/sh -c \"echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export\"")` **WARNING THIS IS DANGEROUS!!!**
- Use a graphical `sudo` replacement like `kdesudo`
- Change your `sudoers` configuration so that the user in question never needs to enter password for `sudo` - not recommended.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't need any authentication or to change the owner of the directory. I only changed the String to a String-Array `"sudo", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export"`

Comment: I updated the answer. I kept the `sudo` part for reference, in case others have a similar issue.